# reverse proxy setup issue

Tags: websphere

I am trying to use Sun java webserver (port 8099) as a Reverse proxy for my websphere application server (port 8051)

I have added this entry in the obj.conf

```
<Object name="reverse-proxy-/">
Route fn="set-origin-server" server="http://example.com:8051"
</Object>

<Object ppath="http:*">
Service fn="proxy-retrieve" method="*"
</Object>
```

So after this when I hit http://example.com:8099 its getting routed correctly to websphere as http://example.com:8051/app

But once I get into my application, its routed forever to my websphere app server i.e after I login with username and password from http://example.com:8099/app/login.html its forwarded forever to http://example.com:8051/app1

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have example.com:8099 in your WebSphere Virtual Host's Aliases list?